# laravel Localization per user

Tags: laravel, localization

How do I change the language of each user? For example, some people don't change the language. Some people change the language.

Middleware :

```
use Closure;
use Auth;

class Localization
  {

   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
     if(\Session::has('locale')) {
       \App::setLocale(\Session::get('locale'));   
      }
     return $next($request);
    }
  }
```

Comment: In config/app.php `locale' => 'en',` will be your default locale (if not set)

Comment: I know, but when I switch to another language, all my users change too.

Comment: here a translation package if you want to use https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization

Comment: Is there a way to write a archive in Session or in a cookie?

Comment: No need to change your middleware,  I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Save the locale for each user in database. This way you can override app's default locale to user's preferred locale in the middleware.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
 if($user = Auth::user()) {
   App::setLocale($user->locale);   
  }
 return $next($request);
}
```

If the your application doesn't require user to be authenticated, you can save locale in session for each user when the user change language.

Comment: Is there a way to write a archive in Session or in a cookie?

Answer (score 1):

Your method is right, no need to change the middleware. You can put the session on user with controller, like this below way.

**Route** :

```
Route::get('/lang',[
    'uses' => 'HomeController@lang',
    'as' => 'lang.index'
]);
```

**Controller** :

```
public function lang(Request $request)
{   
   $user = Auth::user()->id;
   $locale = $request->language;
   App::setLocale($locale);
   session()->put('locale', $locale);
   // if you want to save the locale on your user table, you can do it here
   return redirect()->back();
}
```

**Note** : I added the **GET** method on route, so your URI will be like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/lang?language=en`, and o controller `$request->language` will catch the `language` parameter from your Request. You can modify and use **POST** method instead

Comment: And what do I have to link on the buttons? I have 2 buttons, English and Thai.

Comment: If you put "/ lang", it will error that Function () does not exist.

Comment: You can use button as `<a type="button" "http://127.0.0.1:8000/lang?language=en">English</a>`

Comment: If used as "/lang" error, function () does not exist.

Comment: I can't use "http://127.0.0.1:8000/lang?language=en" because my url is not used. 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: You can use instead `<a type="button" href="/lang?language=en">English</a>`

Comment: You can upload and share the link here. Attach the error message by editing your question

Comment: I use <a type="button" href="/lang?language=en">English</a> 404 Page not found

Comment: Did you define the route `Route::get('/lang',[
    'uses' => 'HomeController@lang',
    'as' => 'lang.index'
]);`???

Comment: I just changed the address of Homecontroller a bit because I use it in -> group (base_path ('app / Modules / routes.php'));. So I changed to Route :: get ('/ lang', [
'user' => '\ App \ Modules \ Home \ HomeController @ lang',
'as' => 'lang.index'
));

Comment: Do you see the route with `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue? If not, let me know about it or let me delete the answer